# After deployment of my MVC project into IIS error appears in Telerik.grid.min.js and Telerik.calender.min.js but in my local host it is working fine

Tags: telerik

I am using visual studio 2012.My MVC application is running fine. But I publish the project and host into IIS in another server it is generating error in browser console that

```
Uncaught TypeError: c(...).tScrollable is not a function
    at new g.grid (VM625 telerik.grid.min.js:1)
 at Object.init (VM625 telerik.grid.min.js:1) 
 at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (VM623 telerik.common.min.js:1)
 at Function.each (VM567 jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3)  
 at init.each (VM567 jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3)  
 at Object.create (VM623 telerik.common.min.js:1)   
 at init.c.fn.tGrid (VM625 telerik.grid.min.js:1)   
 at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (DepartmentList:379)   
 at n (VM567 jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3)   
 at Object.fireWith (VM567 jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3)

 But this error does not appear in my local host.
Is any extra performance has to do with the telerik.grid.min.js and telerik.calender.min.js file.
```

Please suggest me  .

Thanks

Comment: Please share how you are loading kendo files js and css, bundle? When you inspect are they there? are you loading in the right order comparing to jquery?